# Buttons custom content is not rendering at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, wpf-style

I have a `UserControl` hosted in a Windows Forms form. In this `UserControl` I have a `ToolBar` where I have various buttons:

```
<ToolBar>
   <Button Content="{StaticResource AllGreenIcon}"/>
   <Button Content="{StaticResource AllRedIcon}"/>
   <Button Content="{StaticResource RedRectangle}"/>
   <Button Content="{StaticResource GreenRectangle}"/>
</ToolBar>
```

It looks like this in the desinger:

[image: Toolbar with buttons in Designer mode]

The problem is with the buttons where the icon is made of 4 rectangles. The contents are not rendering for these two buttons at runtime.

It looks like this at runtime:

[image: Toolbar at runtime]

The code for the `AllGreenIcon`:

```
<UserControl.Resources>

<Grid x:Key="AllGreenIcon" Height="16" Width="16" Effect="{StaticResource IconDropShadowEffect}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource GreenRectangle}" Margin="0,0,1,1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource GreenRectangle}" Margin="1,0,0,1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource GreenRectangle}" Margin="0,1,1,0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource GreenRectangle}" Margin="1,1,0,0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
</Grid>


</UserControl.Resources>
```

Does anyone have some ideas how could I fix this? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Grid is a container, not a ContentControl. Try to wrap the Grid inside a ContentControl and name the ContentControl with the 'AllGreenIcon' key, instead of name the Grid directly.

Comment: @kennyzx I tried your suggestion, but it didn't work, the result is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This common issue is due to WPF (logical) requirement of each `UIElement` to have a single parent. In your case you are adding to the resources an element - `GreenRectangle`and then you are using this element as the `Content` for multiple `ContentControl`s in your `AllGreenIcon` resource. Each time an element is being connected to the visual tree it will change its parent reference, this guaranties that an element is present only once in the visual tree. 
All your green buttons for example will use the same instance of `GreenRectangle` element. Since each time the `GreenRectangle` is connected to the visual tree its parent is changed only the last item using the `GreenRectange` resource will actually display the element.

In conclusion avoid declaring and using `UIElements` in resources. You should use `Style`s and `Controltemplate`s.

**Note:** in your solution the `AllGreenIcon` grid declared in the resources will have the same problem - cannot be used in two different places in UI at the same time. Use a `ContentTemplate` instead.

**Ex:**

```
<Button ContentTemplate="{StaticResource AllGreenIconTemplate}"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for reminding me about this, I had issues before with this single parent rule. I just forgot about it. Based on your answer I wraped the `Grid`s with a `DataTemplate` and set this to the `Button`s `ContentTemplate`. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to find a sollution by trial and error. Basicly what I did was I've replaced the `ContentControl`s with `Rectangle`s and made a style for the `Rectangle`s.

```
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="GreenLinearGradientBrush" EndPoint="0.5,1" MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox" StartPoint="0.5,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#FF00BD22" Offset="1"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FF218934"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>

<Style x:Key="GreenRectangleStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
   <Setter Property="Width" Value="16"/>
   <Setter Property="Height" Value="16"/>
   <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource GreenLinearGradientBrush}"/>
   <Setter Property="Effect" Value="{StaticResource IconDropShadowEffect}"/>
</Style>

<Grid x:Key="AllGreenIcon" Height="16" Width="16" Effect="{StaticResource IconDropShadowEffect}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Rectangle Margin="0,0,1,1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource GreenRectangleStyle}"/>
    <Rectangle Margin="1,0,0,1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource GreenRectangleStyle}"/>
    <Rectangle Margin="0,1,1,0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource GreenRectangleStyle}"/>
    <Rectangle Margin="1,1,0,0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource GreenRectangleStyle}"/>
</Grid>
```

Does anyone have a better solution?

**edit:**

@Novitchi S had a better solution, based on his answer here is the final version:

```
<Style x:Key="GreenRectangleStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="16"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="16"/>
    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource GreenLinearGradientBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Effect" Value="{StaticResource IconDropShadowEffect}"/>
</Style>

<DataTemplate x:Key="GreenRectangle">
    <Rectangle  Style="{StaticResource GreenRectangleStyle}"/>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="AllGreenIcon">
    <Grid  Height="16" Width="16" Effect="{StaticResource IconDropShadowEffect}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource GreenRectangle}" Margin="0,0,1,1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource GreenRectangle}" Margin="1,0,0,1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource GreenRectangle}" Margin="0,1,1,0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource GreenRectangle}" Margin="1,1,0,0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

.
.
.

```
<ToolBar>
    <Button ContentTemplate="{StaticResource AllGreenIcon}"/>
    <Button ContentTemplate="{StaticResource AllRedIcon}"/>
    <Button ContentTemplate="{StaticResource RedRectangle}"/>
    <Button ContentTemplate="{StaticResource GreenRectangle}"/>
</ToolBar>
```